# GeoServer DateTime Conversion Issue under Tomcat

Tags: geoserver, windows, tomcat, geoserver-manager

I'm having data and time convertion issue with GeoServer 2.19 where the GeoServer returns one day earlier than the actual Oracle database date.

The problem here is that GeoServer 2.19 is running under Tomcat-8.5. Otherwise if I added this **-Duser.timezone=Europe/London** and
**-Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true** parameters directly in the GeoServer start.ini file, that will be resolved automatically.

I'm trying to figure out the fix by referencing different posts here, but nothing has worked so far. To resolve this issue, I have tried a few different approaches.

First, I've set CATALINA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/London in the **System Variables**, but this did not solve the issue.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Next, I've set CATALINA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/London in the **catalina.bat** file, but this also failed to solve the issue.

```
setlocal

@echo>"test_catalina.txt" 
rem Suppress Terminate batch job on CTRL+C
if not ""%1"" == ""run"" goto mainEntry
if "%TEMP%" == "" goto mainEntry
if exist "%TEMP%\%~nx0.run" goto mainEntry
echo Y>"%TEMP%\%~nx0.run"
if not exist "%TEMP%\%~nx0.run" goto mainEntry
echo Y>"%TEMP%\%~nx0.Y"
call "%~f0" %* NUL 2>&1
exit /B %RETVAL%
:mainEntry
del /Q "%TEMP%\%~nx0.run" >NUL 2>&1

rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
:gotHome

if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
echo The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end
:okHome

rem Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not defined
if not "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotBase
set "CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%"
:gotBase

rem Ensure that neither CATALINA_HOME nor CATALINA_BASE contains a semi-colon
rem as this is used as the separator in the classpath and Java provides no
rem mechanism for escaping if the same character appears in the path. Check this
rem by replacing all occurrences of ';' with '' and checking that neither
rem CATALINA_HOME nor CATALINA_BASE have changed
if "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "%CATALINA_HOME:;=%" goto homeNoSemicolon
echo Using CATALINA_HOME:   "%CATALINA_HOME%"
echo Unable to start as CATALINA_HOME contains a semicolon (;) character
goto end
:homeNoSemicolon

if "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "%CATALINA_BASE:;=%" goto baseNoSemicolon
echo Using CATALINA_BASE:   "%CATALINA_BASE%"
echo Unable to start as CATALINA_BASE contains a semicolon (;) character
goto end
:baseNoSemicolon

rem Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
rem but allow them to be specified in setenv.bat, in rare case when it is needed.
set CLASSPATH=

rem Get standard environment variables
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" goto checkSetenvHome
call "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat"
goto setenvDone
:checkSetenvHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat"
:setenvDone

rem Get standard Java environment variables
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat" goto okSetclasspath
echo Cannot find "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat"
echo This file is needed to run this program
goto end
:okSetclasspath
call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat" %1
if errorlevel 1 goto end

rem Add on extra jar file to CLASSPATH
rem Note that there are no quotes as we do not want to introduce random
rem quotes into the CLASSPATH
if "%CLASSPATH%" == "" goto emptyClasspath
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"
:emptyClasspath
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar"

if not "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" == "" goto gotTmpdir
set "CATALINA_TMPDIR=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp"
:gotTmpdir

rem Add tomcat-juli.jar to classpath
rem tomcat-juli.jar can be over-ridden per instance
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" goto juliClasspathHome
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
goto juliClasspathDone
:juliClasspathHome
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
:juliClasspathDone

if not "%JSSE_OPTS%" == "" goto gotJsseOpts
set "JSSE_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048"
:gotJsseOpts
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JSSE_OPTS%"

rem Register custom URL handlers
rem Do this here so custom URL handles (specifically 'war:...') can be used in the security policy
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources"

rem Check for the deprecated LOGGING_CONFIG
rem Only use it if CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG is not set and LOGGING_CONFIG starts with "-D..."
if not "%LOGGING_CONFIG:~0,2%"=="-D" goto noLoggingDeprecation
if not "%CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG%" == "" goto noLoggingDeprecation
set "CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG=%LOGGING_CONFIG%"
:noLoggingDeprecation

if not "%CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG%" == "" goto noJuliConfig
set CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG=-Dnop
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" goto noJuliConfig
set CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
:noJuliConfig

if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" goto noJuliManager
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
:noJuliManager

rem Configure JAVA 9 specific start-up parameters
set "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS% --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
set "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS% --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"
set "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS% --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
set "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS% --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED"
set "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS% --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED"

rem Java 9 no longer supports the java.endorsed.dirs
rem system property. Only try to use it if
rem JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS was explicitly set
rem or CATALINA_HOME/endorsed exists.
set ENDORSED_PROP=ignore.endorsed.dirs
if "%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" == "" goto noEndorsedVar
set ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
goto doneEndorsed
:noEndorsedVar
if not exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed" goto doneEndorsed
set ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
:doneEndorsed

rem ----- Execute The Requested Command ---------------------------------------

echo Using CATALINA_BASE:   "%CATALINA_BASE%"
echo Using CATALINA_HOME:   "%CATALINA_HOME%"
echo Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%"
if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto use_jdk
echo Using JRE_HOME:        "%JRE_HOME%"
goto java_dir_displayed
:use_jdk
echo Using JAVA_HOME:       "%JAVA_HOME%"
:java_dir_displayed
echo Using CLASSPATH:       "%CLASSPATH%"
echo Using CATALINA_OPTS:   "%CATALINA_OPTS%"

set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA%
set MAINCLASS=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
set ACTION=start
set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=
set DEBUG_OPTS=
set JPDA=
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/London

if not ""%1"" == ""jpda"" goto noJpda
set JPDA=jpda
if not "%JPDA_TRANSPORT%" == "" goto gotJpdaTransport
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
:gotJpdaTransport
if not "%JPDA_ADDRESS%" == "" goto gotJpdaAddress
set JPDA_ADDRESS=localhost:8000
:gotJpdaAddress
if not "%JPDA_SUSPEND%" == "" goto gotJpdaSuspend
set JPDA_SUSPEND=n
:gotJpdaSuspend
if not "%JPDA_OPTS%" == "" goto gotJpdaOpts
set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%
:gotJpdaOpts
shift
:noJpda

if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto doDebug
if ""%1"" == ""run"" goto doRun
if ""%1"" == ""start"" goto doStart
if ""%1"" == ""stop"" goto doStop
if ""%1"" == ""configtest"" goto doConfigTest
if ""%1"" == ""version"" goto doVersion

echo Usage:  catalina ( commands ... )
echo commands:
echo   debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
echo   debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
echo   jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
echo   run               Start Catalina in the current window
echo   run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
echo   start             Start Catalina in a separate window
echo   start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
echo   stop              Stop Catalina
echo   configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml
echo   version           What version of tomcat are you running?
goto end

:doDebug
shift
set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJDB%
set DEBUG_OPTS=-sourcepath "%CATALINA_HOME%\..\..\java"
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd

:doRun
shift
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd

:doStart
shift
if "%TITLE%" == "" set TITLE=Tomcat
set _EXECJAVA=start "%TITLE%" %_RUNJAVA%
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd

:doStop
shift
set ACTION=stop
set CATALINA_OPTS=
goto execCmd

:doConfigTest
shift
set ACTION=configtest
set CATALINA_OPTS=
goto execCmd

:doVersion
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% -classpath "%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
goto end


:execCmd
rem Get remaining unshifted command line arguments and save them in the
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
:setArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
shift
goto setArgs
:doneSetArgs

rem Execute Java with the applicable properties
if not "%JPDA%" == "" goto doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
:doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
:doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
:doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end

:end
```

Comment: Its not clear that you are passing CATALINA_OPTS to the tomcat instantiation. Trying adding `%CATALINA_OPTS%` between the `%JAVA_HOME%` and `-classpath` parts of the execCmd section. Otherwise, can you show the actual lines in `catalina.bat` (not a screenshot)?

Comment: Please have a look at the lines of my catalina.bat file, which I've added here now.

Comment: Looks like it should be OK. Did you do a full restart after making that change?

Comment: Yes, After every change, I stopped and restarted the Tomcat service.

Comment: do you think I should include the below parameter as well?                               
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/London -Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true"

Comment: There is no difference even I added the "-Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true" parameter.